# Tomcat6 behind Apache2.2 proxy with SSL

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I use Apache 2.2 with SSL as proxy(mod_jk). Behind it running tomcat6(without SSL) . When I use http connection everything work ok eg. for tomcat manager "http://localhost/manager/html", but when I try "https://localhost/manager/html" I get "The requested URL /manager/html was not found on this server" message . Should I add something to uirworkemap.properties.
I would be grateful for help.

I should add that I have to use Windows XP.

**I mean somethin like this:
 -> https -> apache2.2 -> http -> tomcat6 
 <- https <- apache2.2 <- http <- tomcat6**

Apache logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2010:13:34:34 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 210
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2010:13:34:34 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

My workers.properties

```
worker.list=wlb,jkstatus
worker.ajp13w.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13w.host=localhost
worker.ajp13w.port=8009
worker.wlb.type=lb
worker.wlb.balance_workers=ajp13w
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

uirworkemap.properties

```
/manager/html/*=wlb
/manager/html=wlb
/jkmanager=jkstatus
```

mod_jk in httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

Listen 80
#Listen 443

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

#*************** JK_MODULE SECTION ***************
# load module

LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

<IfModule jk_module>

    # We need a workers file exactly once
    # and in the global server
    JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

    # Our JK error log
    # You can (and should) use rotatelogs here
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

    # Our JK log level (trace,debug,info,warn,error)
    JkLogLevel info

    # Our JK shared memory file
    JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm

    # Define a new log format you can use in any CustomLog in order
    # to add mod_jk specific information to your access log.
    # LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Cookie}i\" \"%{Set-Cookie}o\" %{pid}P %{tid}P %{JK_LB_FIRST_NAME}n %{JK_LB_LAST_NAME}n ACC %{JK_LB_LAST_ACCESSED}n ERR %{JK_LB_LAST_ERRORS}n BSY %{JK_LB_LAST_BUSY}n %{JK_LB_LAST_STATE}n %D" extended_jk

    # This option will reject all requests, which contain an
    # encoded percent sign (%25) or backslash (%5C) in the URL
    # If you are sure, that your webapp doesn't use such
    # URLs, enable the option to prevent double encoding attacks.
    # Since: 1.2.24
    # JkOptions +RejectUnsafeURI

    # After setting JkStripSession to "On", mod_jk will
    # strip all ";jsessionid=..." from request URLs it
    # does *not* forward to a backend.
    # This is useful, if all links in a webapp use
    # URLencoded session IDs and parts of the static
    # content should be delivered directly by Apache.
    # Of course you can also do it with mod_rewrite.
    # Since: 1.2.21
    # JkStripSession On

    # Start a separate thread for internal tasks like
    # idle connection probing, connection pool resizing
    # and load value decay.
    # Run these tasks every JkWatchdogInterval seconds.
    # Since: 1.2.27
    JkWatchdogInterval 60

    # Configure access to jk-status and jk-manager
    # If you want to make this available in a virtual host,
    # either move this block into the virtual host
    # or copy it logically there by including "JkMountCopy On"
    # in the virtual host.
    # Add an appropriate authentication method here!


    # If you want to put all mounts into an external file
    # that gets reloaded automatically after changes
    # (with a default latency of 1 minute),
    # you can define the name of the file here.
    JkMountFile conf/extra/uriworkermap.properties

    # Example for Mounting a context to the worker "balancer"
    # The URL syntax "a|b" instantiates two mounts at once,
    # the first one is "a", the second one is "ab".
    # JkMount /myapp|/* balancer

    # Example for UnMounting requests for all workers
    # using a simple URL pattern
    # Since: 1.2.26
    # JkUnMount /myapp/static/* *

    # Example for UnMounting requests for a named worker
    # JkUnMount /myapp/images/* balancer

    # Example for UnMounting requests using regexps
    # SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "\.(htm|html|css|gif|jpg|js)$" no-jk

    # Example for setting a reply timeout depending on the requets URL
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/transactions/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=600000

    # Example for disabling reply timeouts for certain request URLs
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/reports/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=0

    # IMPORTANT: Mounts and virtual hosts
    # If you are using VirtualHost elements, you
    # - can put mounts only used in some virtual host into its VirtualHost element 
    # - can copy all global mounts to it using "JkMountCopy On" inside the VirtualHost
    # - can copy all global mounts to all virtual hosts by putting
    #   "JkMountCopy All" into the global server
    # Since: 1.2.26

</IfModule>

#************* END OF JK_MODULE SECTION *************


<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin blabla@admin.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName lcjws047.global.ad:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>


ErrorLog "logs/error.log"


LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var


</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://lcjws047.global.ad/subscription_info.html
#

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

httpd-ssl.conf with virtual host:

```
Listen 443

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#
#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
#
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#SSLSessionCache         "dbm:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_scache"
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization. 
SSLMutex default

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
ServerName server.pl:443
ServerAdmin blabla@gmail.com
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
#   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server-dsa.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/server-dsa.key"    

#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

#SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also have Tomcat automatically switch to HTTPS when someone browses to http://localhost/manager/html. Add to ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml, just before the close tag for **security-constraint**:

```
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

Also configure your AJP connector in ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml to forward to the standard HTTPS port (443):

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to add mod_ssl and configure same for your Apache.

Refer :

http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign_ubuntu.html

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html

Adding Virtual host for SSL

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName server_name
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile certificate_file_path
    SSLCertificateKeyFile certificate_key_path
    SSLCertificateChainFile  certificate_chain_path

    RedirectMatch ^/$ /

    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs" >
        SSLRequireSSL
            #other options which you require
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't past whole httpd.conf, I have mod_ssl.

Comment: I read your links but I don't understand how they can help me. It's seems that SSL on Apache work ok, when I type "https://localhost" I get worning about untrust certificate(I generated It by myself). Problem Is that I can't get answer from tomcat through https proxy.

Comment: you will need to add virtual host for ssl 
something like:
Adde in answer

Comment: I'am using default virtual host defined in httpd-ssl.conf. I add rewrite url in virtual host, but It's not solution for my problem. I want secure connection from outside to apache proxy. It seems for me like apache proxy sends whole url to tomcat and when I type "https://localhost/manager/html" proxy send its directly to tomcat, but my tomcat doesn't now what to do with https because it doesen't has SSL on. It is possible to map for eg. "https://localhost/manager/html" to "http://localhost/manager/html" in proxy and send that to tomcat.